Query to retrieve the first attendance time for each staff member for a specific branch
I have data, I want to bring first attendance time for each employee for each day for "branch one"
The data:
Branch        USER ID            date       time
branch one  1              20240101 071500
branch one  1              20240101 072015
branch one  2              20240102 072502
branch one  2              20240102 081500
branch one  1              20240103 072001
branch one  2              20240104 072502
branch one  1              20240105 071501
branch one  1              20240106 072000
branch two  2              20240107 072055


Result should be like this:
Branch         USER ID     date         time
branch one     1       20240101       071500
branch one     2       20240102       072502
branch one     1       20240103       072001
branch one     2       20240104       072502
branch one     1       20240105       071501
branch one     1       20240106       072000

Note:

date format should be "01/01/2024", Time 24 hours without seconds "07:15"
I will select more columns from database like name

Anyone can help with the query? I use SQL server as database
Use min function with group by will return the data but I need to bring more details about user like his name etc.,
Example:
select min(time), date, user_id ,user_name
from table x 
group by user_id, date

When I use this way, I can't select any additional columns like "user name" from table as I used group by
Thanks
